# Union Operation in REST Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

We are making REST base search to sharepoint. However we have to make 2 different searches. For example, if we ask `"indian employees"` then sharepoint does not return a document which contains India (Stemming does not work here). And if we ask `"indian OR employees"` then the sort order of sharepoint is as per individual keywords. So we are firing 2 searches one with "indian employees" and then "indian OR employees".

All good, but the time is being taken by 2 queries is high. Is there a way so that we can union these two types of queries like in CAML query [How to make a CAML union query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20878/how-to-make-a-caml-query-union). Though CAML query does not work in REST query.

Also head of `ANY(indian employees)` query but I think that is equivalent to OR query only.